# finding elements in edge and IE with selenium java based

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

i try to find elements in edge or IE and it look like that these two browsers are not working with Xpath, more over, i tried to launce my automation in parallel with cheome, IE, Edge, and in Xpath its not working at all (just in chrome it works) but when i change it to css.. it start working

second thing that i noticed that at the CTRL+F while looking for elements, its not highlighted like in chrome

so is there any way to work with xpath? also, it can be that elements in chrome are not the same in edge or IE with css for example? and if so, how can i run in parallel test with that browsers?

Comment: Based on my experience the xpath locators for IE and Edge is a bit different from Chrome, but it should still work on Selenium. Can you give an example of what you have tried?

Comment: for example, go into
`www.ynet.co.il`
in chrome, try these in CSS  `[alt="תרבות"]` or in Xpath   `//img[@alt="תרבות"]`
in edge try to work with these Xpath and you will get nothing, try to work with CSS and you will find the element

Answer (score 0):

This xpath should work in all browsers:

```
"//foo[contains(@bar,'xy')]"
"//a[contains(@href,'xy')]"
```